# how we can start our application as Iphone is switch on

Tags: ios4

is it possible to start an user develop application automatically by system when we switch on iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Not on a standard non jailbroken device.

Comment: Hi,theChrisKent. Thanks,How can We do this with jailbroken iPhone?